# Parsing foreach within foreach

Tags: php

Im having some what of a problem and i need guidance. Im trying to parse 3 csv files and put them inside a foreach loop but its going horribly wrong. The string $stockClose does not change it remains the same through out the loop, $nas_stock changes every 20 loops and it is suppose to change every loop, the only that seems to be working correctly is $sp500_stock, im not sure why

```
    $currentMonth = date('n');
    $currentMonth = $currentMonth - 1;
    $prevcurrentMonth = date('n');
    $prevcurrentMonth = $prevcurrentMonth - 2;
    $currentDay = date('j');
    $lastDay = $currentDay - 6;
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    $filedow = file_get_contents("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EDJI&a=$prevcurrentMonth&b=$lastDay&c=$currentYear&d=$currentMonth&e=$currentDay&f=$currentYear&g=d&ignore=.csv");

    $filenas = file_get_contents("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EIXIC&a=$prevcurrentMonth&b=$lastDay&c=$currentYear&d=$currentMonth&e=$currentDay&f=$currentYear&g=d&ignore=.csv");

    $filesp500 = file_get_contents("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EGSPC&a=$prevcurrentMonth&b=$lastDay&c=$currentYear&d=$currentMonth&e=$currentDay&f=$currentYear&g=d&ignore=.csv");

    $stockcontent = str_replace('Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close', '',  $filedow);
    $stockcontent = trim($stockcontent);

$stockcontentex = str_getcsv($stockcontent, "\n");

    $stocknas = str_replace('Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close', '',  $filenas);
    $stocknas = trim($stocknas);
$stocknasex = str_getcsv($stocknas, "\n");

    $stocksp500 = str_replace('Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close', '',  $filesp500);
    $stocksp500 = trim($stocksp500);
$stocksp500ex = str_getcsv($stocksp500, "\n");

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    $_str = '';  
    $_str .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dow Jones');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nasdaq');
    data.addColumn('number', 'S&P 500');
    data.addRows([";
    $tstr = "";
        $_str = '';  
$_str .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dow Jones');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nasdaq');
    data.addColumn('number', 'S&P 500');
    data.addRows([";
    $tstr = "";
        foreach($stocknasex as $nas){
            $nasex = explode(',',$nas);
                $nas_stock = $nasex[4];
        }

        foreach($stocksp500ex as $sp500){
            $sp500ex = explode(',',$sp500);
                $sp500_stock = $sp500ex[4];
        }
        foreach($stockcontentex as $stockexplode){
        $stockex = explode(',',$stockexplode);
        $stockexdate = explode('-', $stockex[0]);
        $stockYear = $stockexdate[0];
        $stockMonth = $stockexdate[1] - 1 ;
        $stockDay = $stockexdate[2];
        $stockHigh = $stockex[2];
        $stockLow = $stockex[3];
        $stockClose = $stockex[4];




    }

     for($i=0; $i<=30; $i++){
     $tstr = '[new Date('.$stockYear.', '.$stockMonth.', '.$stockDay.'), '.$stockClose.', '.$nas_stock.', '.$sp500_stock.'],'. "\n".$tstr;
     }
     $_str = $_str.$tstr;
     $_str .= "]); 
    var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {
                            //'allValuesSuffix': '%', // A suffix that is added to all values
                            'colors': ['#12577F', '#769422', '#999999'], // The colors to be used
                            'displayAnnotations': true,
                            'displayExactValues': true, // Do not truncate values (i.e. using K suffix)
                            'displayRangeSelector' : false, // Do not sow the range selector
                            'displayZoomButtons': true, // DO not display the zoom buttons
                            'legendPosition': 'newRow', // Can be sameRow
                            //'max': 600, // Override the automatic default
                            //'min':  500, // Override the automatic default
                            'scaleColumns': [0, 1], // Have two scales, by the first and second lines
                            'scaleType': 'allmaximized', // See docs...
                            'thickness': 2, // Make the lines thicker
                                });
  }
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script><div style='float:left; border:1px solid #ccc;'>
<div id='chart_div' style='width: 500px; height: 230px;'></div></div>";

    return $_str;
    break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  You have *nested* loops.  The entire `$sp500` loop is inside the body of the `$nas` loop, which means that `$nas` won't repeat until `$sp500` goes all the way through the first value of `$stocksp500ex`.  And the `$nas` loop, in turn, is wholly contained within the body of the `$stockexplode` loop, which means that `$stockexplode` won't advance until `$nas` has gone all the way through `$stocknasex`.

They're like digits in a counter.  The innermost loop is the rightmost digit, and the next loop out doesn't click until the inner one rolls over.

**EDIT**:
If you're trying to iterate over all three arrays in parallel, you should use one loop instead of three nested ones.  Maybe something like this?

```
  $nasex_count = count($stocknasex);
  $sp500_count = count($stocksp500ex);
  $content_count = count($stockcontentex);
  $max = max($nasex_count, $sp500_count, $content_count);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $max; ++$i) {
    if ($i < $nasex_count) {
        ... do something with $stocknasex[$i] ...
    }

    if ($i < $sp500_count) {
        ... do something with $stocksp500ex[$i] ...
    }

    if ($i < $content_count) {
        ... do something with $stockcontentex[$i] ...
    }
  }
```

Of course, if you know going in that all three arrays are the same size, you can skip the `max()` and conditionals.

Comment: I went ahead and adjusted my code, I understand what your saying but im not too sure how to fixed my problem. I want all of them to loop through without the previous one stoping it. I took it out of the foreach loop and put a for loop on it but that just makes them all repeat the same output on each loop instead of advancing, I appreciate you taking a loop and explaining that to me

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Step away from nitty-gritty details like for loops; at a high level, what are you trying to do? Take data from three CSV files and do what with it?  Merge it into one file?

Comment: take data from all 3 files and make them print in one loop

Comment: OK, still using irrelevant implementation details.  If I came to you with this problem to solve, I would probably not use the word 'loop' anywhere.  I assume you're producing a report?

Comment: im sorry for be complicated it but the out looks like this and I also included the output im trying to achieve http://pastebin.com/pVveKUP6

Comment: Right.  My edit should be what you need, then.  One loop, not three.

Comment: yes but i need the results in 1 string like this one $tstr = '[new Date('.$stockYear.', '.$stockMonth.', '.$stockDay.'), '.$stockClose.', '.$nas_stock.', '.$sp500_stock.'],'. "\n".$tstr;

Comment: so build up the string inside the one loop.  `$str = new date(....);  if ($i < $count_nas) { $str .= ",$stocknasex[$i]"; } else { $str .= ","; }  
if ($i < $count_sp500) { $str .= ",$stocksp500ex[$i]"; } { else { $str .= "," }`...